# Spin Tool Cursor Not Showing/Snapping to 3D cursor

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am trying to use the spin tool on my mesh but the tool is not appearing in my window. I have the cursor snapped to the face of the object itself but I do not see the spin tool when I have it turned on. I have modeled other meshes with the spin tool within the same blend file without issue, it just suddenly stopped showing up when I wanted to use it on this mesh and subsequent meshes. Even when zoomed out I do not see the tool.

[image: no spin tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally animating your scene (e.g. pressed `space`) and some tools do not show during the animation. Your image shows the `Anim Player` at the bottom of the screen, which means you are animating.